# Data format compatibility between Thrift versions

Tags: java, serialization, upgrade, backwards-compatibility, thrift

I am trying to upgrade a system that uses Thrift 0.2 libraries for communication. Since this is rather old version (latest stable is 0.5), and there have been alleged significant improvements to performance (in 0.4) I was hoping to upgrade. However, I could not find information regarding whether there have been incompatible changes to underlying data format. Based on versioning scheme, one would hope there was not; but since these are still pre-1.0 versions, maybe there is less expectation for stability.

The reason I am hoping to learn that data format itself was backwards compatible is that it would allow upgrades to components to occur one by one.

Anyway: I was hoping that someone with more information could point me to right documentation.

Comment: After playing with 0.5.0, I noticed that generated code is not plug-and-play -- base classes that implementations extend have different API -- but fortunately wire-format does look identical (size did not change at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... instead of using byte[] as the underlying data type for binary fields, we’ve switched to using ByteBuffer. The means that we can avoid doing unnecessary byte array allocation and copies during deserialization. This approach is a full 2.5x times faster than the old way, and that’s not even accounting for the reduction in garbage collection time. **You’ll definitely have to make some code changes to get the upgrade**, but you should still find it worthwhile.

Taken from ["Thrift 0.4.0 Released"](http://blog.rapleaf.com/dev/2010/08/24/thrift-0.4.0-released/) document. Related changes in the source code: ["Switch binary field implementation from byte[] to ByteBuffer"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-830).

Comment: Btw; I finally had a chance to play with newer version of Thrift, and although change to specific part may give 2.5x boost, overall boost for reading part of my use case was +50% (i.e took ~33% less time to read same amount of data). That's pretty nice improvement.